# Problems with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to open a local html file within the same directory of the python file, but i still get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Even though is in the same directory and I have tried to move the HTML File from places but no fix

Here is the code and the directory that im using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html", "r") as f:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/28/2021  9:12 AM            114 main.py
-a---          11/26/2021  7:35 PM           1450 math_page.html
```

Comment: share the output of `dir` command.

Comment: remove the comment and post the data as part of the question. **Note** - run the dir command from the folder where you have the py script and the html

Comment: sorry kind of new to this

Comment: Remove images - post text ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

The actual html name is `math_page.html`. Your code try to load `index.html`.

So *No such file or directory* makes perfect sense.

Comment: is that i tried to change the name of the code to see if it works but it doesn't

Comment: If the python script and the html file are in the SAME folder and you run the py script from that folder - it **should** work. It looks like one of those pre conditions is not true on your side.

Comment: i found the problem and it was that i needed to copy the relative path, still thanks :)

Comment: You may accept the answer. Good luck.